# GDB IA32 seeing whats at a memory address?

Tags: memory, gdb, att, x86

i have the instruction

```
cmp    %eax,0x18(%esp,%ebx,4)
```

I know it means compare whatever is at the address with eax, but i cannot figure out how to see whats at the address.

i tried p/s the address, x/s my bad calculation of the address, all failed. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> any help

You didn't show us what you've tried. Something like this should work:

```
x/x (0x18 + $esp + 4 * $ebx)
```

Comment: you just beat me to this, i just figured out that GDB can do the calculations for me haha stupid. thanks tho

Comment: @user2038460 "you just beat me to this" beat you to what? answering your own question?

Comment: to posting that solution as an update on the question then asking if thats the best way to do it lol